# IF/ELSE Conditions on Ruby hash

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I want to set up a Ruby partial that takes a 'type' then, depending on that type, spits out a `<li>` with defined elements (such as an icon, a particular label, etc)

Here's my working .erb chunk

```
      <ul>
        <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_links %>
          <% sermon_links.each do |link| %>

            <% if locals.has_key? :type == "download" %>

            <li>
              <i class="material-icons">music_note</i>
              <a href="<%= link[:hyperlink] %>">Download this sermon (~5mb)</a>
            </li>

            <% else %>

            <% if locals.has_key? :type == "passage" %>

            <li>
              <i class="material-icons">link</i>
              <a href="<%= link[:hyperlink] %>"><%= sermon_passage %> on Bible Gateway</a>
            </li>

            <% end %>

          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

And then I'd call it in the HTML file like this:

```
  :sermon_links => [
    { :type => "download", :hyperlink => "https://www.biblegateway.com/resources/matthew-henry/John" }
  ]
```

I'm 99% sure the problem is how I'm setting the 'IF type equals THIS' (`<% if locals.has_key? :type == "download" %>`) I'm a newbie to Ruby on Rails so any help in this area would be really appreciated :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite as follows:

```
<ul>
  <% if locals.has_key? :sermon_links %>
    <% sermon_links.each do |link| %>
      <% if link[:type].present? && link[:type] == "download" %>
        <li>
          <i class="material-icons">music_note</i>
          <a href="<%= link[:hyperlink] %>">Download this sermon (~5mb)</a>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <% if link[:type].present? && link[:type] == "passage" %>
          <li>
            <i class="material-icons">link</i>
            <a href="<%= link[:hyperlink] %>"><%= sermon_passage %> on Bible Gateway</a>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. That logic works out, so it's good to know I was thinking on the right line :) I'm getting a syntax error with the above solution. `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end /Users/Beau/Documents/Repositories/fac-build-2016/source/partials/_sermon-page.erb:138: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end end;end;end;end ^` any clues?

Comment: Any more thought on this, Khanh? :)